Finding channel gain of an OFDM modulated signal
I am trying to implement an adaptive modulation based on CSI using the SNR values from an OFDM-modulated signal. I found a formula in a research paper to find the instantaneous SNR which is the average SNR multiplied with the magnitude squared of the channel gain. I have been looking for a formula or a way to compute the channel gain, but couldn't find any. My idea is to calculate the instantaneous SNR for the first symbol. Can anyone help me, please? Here is a snippet of my codes:
qpsk = PSK(M_PSK)
ofdm_qpsk = OFDM(fft_size, cp_size, num_used_subcarriers)

# Generate some random data to modulate with QPSK
data_psk = np.random.randint(0, M_PSK, num_symbols)

# Modulate the data
qpsk_symbols = qpsk.modulate(data_psk)

# OFDM Modulate the QPSK symbols
ofdm4_symbols = ofdm_qpsk.modulate(qpsk_symbols)

# Step 1: Calculate received signal power for each subcarrier (absolute square of the received signal)
received_signal_power = np.abs(received_ofdm_symbols)**2

# Step 2: Calculate the channel gain for each subcarrier
channel_gain = received_signal_power / np.mean(received_signal_power, axis=0)


"gain" is just the magnitude of the channel coefficient.
You're done; nothing special you need to do: every subcarrier's gain is just the magnitude of its channel coefficient, which is what you usually mean when you say "CSI".
You'll find that water filling as power allocation method for OFDM carriers has been intensely studied and is the subject of multiple textbook introductions to multicarrier systems in general and OFDM especially¹. It's optimal under some assumptions (perfect knowledge of per-subcarrier SNR, constant channels, and no limit on how much power gets concentrated in carriers, and ability to get close to Shannon's capacity limit). From power allocation follows SNR per carrier and thus number of bits transportable per channel access; so, for a large set of relatively likely scenario, your problem has been solved already, in a matter that you can't be better!
So: I'd read up on water filling, and pay special attention to the assumption made on every step of its introduction. Then, compare the assumptions made there with the assumptions you make. Identify where they differ. Then, come up with a system, either based on the water filling algorithm or completely different, and compare its performance to that would one apply water filling to your assumptions.

¹ I think it's both in the Proakis/Salehi and the Viswanath/Tse textbooks; I'd probably go for Proakis' book, as your university will have it in its library, and I think in that section, the math in Proakis is "good enough", and Viswanath & Tse might shock you a bit with too much optimization terminology. I don't have a modern Goldsmith textbook on hand, but water-filling for time-variant channels is part of her PhD thesis, so that it's probably also covered in her Wireless Communications textbook, too. I'm almost certain she covers it for MIMO in her MIMO textbook, but I'm not sure how familiar you are with MIMO.

Thanks that was helpful. I will look into it
